Looking solution to handle big query for reporting data from AWS Aurora Postgresql
I am having a AWS Aurora Postgresql Cluster with an Severless instance as Primary instance and a Provisioned Instance as Replica instance. Primary instance will serve query from Application only and Replica instance wills serve query from QuickSight for Reporting.
My problem is that QuickSight queries are complicate with joining from multiple tables. My data also is growthing to 10 Gbps. Each query from QuickSight take long time to complete and I cannot continue upgrade my Replica instance class. I'm also using Slice of QuickSight but not helpul.
I am looking for a solution as a buffer between Postgresql and QuickSight to reduce database workload.
Can someone help me with any keyword suggestion?

If the problem is complex queries for dashboards, then the traditional method is to pre-compute this data. For example, every half-hour the system might calculate new totals and store the information in a table. Then, the dashboard just needs to query these stored summaries instead of continually recalculating the amounts.

I already recalculating data every hours. The data will be saved on SPICE for subsequent query. However, the number of datasets and query is large and I'm still looking for additional method to help more reducing database workload. Thank for your help @JohnRotenstein.

Although it is difficult to understand the bottleneck without monitoring insides, I will give it a try.
Did you try increasing BufferCacheHitRatio ?
Next one would be to check if you use a the proper type of replication: Understand replication capabilities
Are you using Auto Scaling with Aurora Replicas as this also might be a solution?
I hope this suggestions help.

I dont use Autot Scaling for Replicas because I just want to using 1 replica. I didn't increase BufferCacheHitRatio yet. I wiill try this. Thank for your suggestion @zhrist.
